Felt QX60 Upgrade
Bought this hybrid from a friend a few years back. Currently doing weekly 40-60km rides, mostly on (bad) roads, with the occasional forest trail adventure. Long story short, I'm either looking at getting a new gravel bike (1500$ to 2000$ budget) or upgrading my current one if I could get similar levels of performance for similar money. I mostly ride flat terrain, so never actually felt the need for better brakes, but I'm not very happy with the shifting, especially on the front. Hence why I end up riding mostly in the middle gear of my crankset.
Specs of the bike are here: https://www.bikeroar.com/products/felt/qx60-2013/specs

if I could get similar levels of performance?  How do you define "performance"?

Based on the question the only problem is front derailleur shifting? If so, you can save a lot of money by adjusting the front derailleur. It is within the capability of the Shimano FD-M191 to shift well. It would be good to do an evaluation of what you do and don't like to get an accurate picture of what you do/don't need so you can estimate cost/benefit.

It really depends on what you consider by performance: if you are overall happy with the bike, except the front shifting, a transmission upgrade would suffice and will cost much less than a new bike (that being said, maybe the some basic service would be sufficient, derailleur cable replacement and tuning). There has been some movement in entry level single chainring/wide range cassettes transmission recently (Shimano CUES and Essa, Microshift Advent (X),...). I wouldn't do more on a bike of this range, as the parts and labour will quickly reach the price of a new bike of the same category, but with modern components.
If you want to change the bike, it's of course another story.
For what it's worth: to use both an upgraded hybrid - equivalent in specs to a $1500 hybrid and a gravel bike, I found the gravel bike to be more comfy on long rides (over 3 hours) and not too rough terrain. The gravel is also noticeably faster on smooth surfaces - tarmac and smooth gravel/forest paths (about 3km/h average on 50+km rides). But on rougher or more technical terrain, the front suspension (even with 65mm of travel) and flat bar have an edge - note the fork has been upgraded, and I service it: not servicing a suspension results in lesser performance. I mostly bought the gravel because I joined a road/gravel cycling club in the meantime, and I couldn't keep up with the roadies with the hybrid, but I still prefer to use the hybrid for gravel activities.

Thank you! Would you mind suggesting some upgrade paths?  To be honest I like the idea of retrofitting hydraulic disc brakes as well, not for the performance of it necessarily, but because I like to tinker and think that would be a good project.

@Alex better to ask a new question for that. My upgrade path was linked to the replacement of worn parts (you can see the path in the answer I linked). That being said, brakes are a not an obvious one: if the frame doesn't have the mounts (hybrids of the late 2000's/early 2010's have sometimes mounts for v-brake and disc), you can basically forget it. If the frame has the mounts, you'll need to replace the wheels as well, and maybe the fork, and that only for a marginal improvement over good v-brakes.

(thinking about it: note that my upgrade path was also cost-effective because I started from a more recent bike and did only incremental changes: for example, the jump from 9 to 10 speed only required a new cassette (that was worn) chain (that was worn), and rear derailleur and shifter, but I could keep the crankset and FD). In your case, rim brakes, 40mm fork and 7-speed would require much more "cascade changes" - if parts are available).

If you like tinkering, hydraulic rim brakes are a thing :)

Have created a new question for the upgrade path https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/94448/upgrade-path-for-felt-qx60-2013 , as suggested by @Renaud

@Alex Sorry "that" referred to the brake question, not the upgrade path. The upgrade path was what I suggested in my answer: just the transmission with a modern 1x, with a clutch derailleur (CUES for example - crankset, cassette, chain rear derailleur, shifter), I would not spend too much this kind of bike, because will quickly arrive to the price of a new bike.

My bad, I deleted that question. The cues looks like exactly the thing I'm looking for. Is it just a case of getting a gearset, crankset, rear shifter, derailleur and brake levers. Right now I have the brake levers and shifters as combo.

@Alex the other question would have been closed anyway, an "upgrade path" is too much of an opinion-based question, and I doubt there would a different answer than the one posted here. You may also need to buy a bottom bracket - depends on the CUES level you choose (4000 requires a "square tapered", that was common on early 2010' bikes — not familiar with Suntour cranksets, but 6000 uses a different system).

Thank you again! A friend mentioned I might need to replace the rear wheel as well because my current wheel/hub wouldn't fit a 10/11 cog cassette?

@Alex to my knowledge, that shouldn't be an issue, there's only one size of freehub body for MTBs, that works from 7- to 12-speed, as long as the smallest sprocket has 11 teeth (for road, or cassettes with smaller small sprockets, it is a bit more complex). But I'm not 100% sure - there are sometimes exceptions with 6 or 7-speeds, so better to take a photo and ask a new question (my city bike is from the late 2000's and has a standard hub that would work with a linkglide without any issue).
